# How do I set a board as default at Trello?

Tags: trello

Currently, Trello defaults to the *Welcome Board*.
Is there a way to set another board as default?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean it defaults to the "Welcome Board"?

Comment: Do you mean as the default first board for users you're inviting, or for the first board you go to in Trello?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, this would be the board that loads when you go to http://trello.com. This is a fairly common request, and something we might consider adding as a feature.

In the meantime, boards are bookmarkable.

Comment: Rich, this is probably a small enhancement and one that would be helpful. I imagine most of us delete the Welcome board within a week or two of using the software so our new default screen every time we go to Trello is "Welcome board is deleted". It's not terrible but it's annoying to see that every day, sometimes many times a day.

Comment: @TomWilliams can you contact us at support@trello.com to help us understand this?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to copy the URL of the board that I want as my default, and bookmark it.